# Angular + Phonegap + WordPress Post Request Failing

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, wordpress, cordova

When using `phonegap serve` to test out my Angular based app, GET requests work just fine, but POST requests are failing.

I'm using WordPress as my backend, and all of my AJAX requests are directed to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, and then I use action hooks to run the appropriate function for each request. GET requests work just fine this way and will return expected results. POST requests, however, are returning 0 no matter what I do. If I use Weinre to inspect the app, the request is sent successfully and gets a 200 response from WordPress, but the response body simply contains "0" instead of my specified response.

In Weinre, my request appears to be sending correctly with all required variables, but it's still not working. Here is a screenshot of the request in Weinre:

[image: Weinre post request screenshot]

The only thought that I had is that the request payload object seems to have quotes around the keys, and I'm not sure if this is throwing WP off. Has anybody experienced this or know why I might be experiencing this?

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue.

Comment: Very first line in my function is:

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Comment: Honestly it seems like the function isn't even being called by WP. If I switch it to GET, it all works. POST doesn't though...

Comment: Are you handling OPTIONS?

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure I understand. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Also just a note, testing the same URL locally from my Cocoa Rest Client app, it all works, so I don't think the issue is with the server responding, but rather with the Phonegap / Angular app not passing the POST data correctly.

Comment: Maybe a domain whitelist issue?  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: Like I said, if I switch everything to GET, it works. I would assume that a domain whitelisting issue would mean GET wouldn't work either right?

Comment: Plus I just checked and this line is already in my config.xml:

`<access origin="*" />`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question. Turns out that the way Angular handles POST data prevents users from using `$_POST` to access data and instead requires users to use `file_get_contents("php://input");` In order to get WP ajax to work, data had to be accessible using the `$_POST` super global. In order to make Angular work correctly, I included jQuery in my app and ran the postData object that I was sending through jQuery's `$.param()` method. This "stringified" my data before passing it to the server, enabling WordPress ajax to work correctly. More info on this here:

http://angulartricks.com/how-to-do-http-post-with-angularjs-in-php/